# Update test case execution (by uploading xml file) in testlink with Testcase Unique custom field

Tags: xml, testlink

I have configured test link (Version 1.9.12), everything looks good but I have been trying to update test case execution by uploading xml file. It works fine if xml uses test case ID (External or internal) but I would like to use test case name or custom field.
For this I have searched in web and found a link(given below) where they have attached some files which has bits and pieces of code to modify in my existing [testlink project](http://mantis.testlink.org/view.php?id=3843).
After going through the `.diff` files I have understood that I have to modify couple of existing files (mentioned below) in my testlink.

1. `/lib/functions/testcase.class.php`
2. `/lib/results/resultsImport.php`

the xml I have been importing is shown below, can someone help me out. Many thanks in advance.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- TestLink - www.teamst.org - xml to allow results import -->
<results>
    <testproject name="Target" prefix="DT_Target" />
    <testplan name="TestPlan1" />
    <build name="Test Build Auto" />
    <testcase external_id="DT_Target-730">
        <!--<testcase name="MyTestCaseName1">-->
        <linkby custom_field="checkmate_id" value="MyTestCaseCF1" />
        <result>F</result>
        <notes>YYYYYYYYYYYY</notes>
        <timestamp></timestamp>
    </testcase>
</results>
```